# Solution to nonlinear heat equation with time variant Neumann type boundary conditions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

The non-linear form of the heat equation can be written as:

$\rho(T) c_p(T) \frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \left ( k(T) \frac{\partial T}{\partial z} \right).$

Assuming the following boundary and initial conditions:

$ T(z,0) = T_0 ,$

$-k  \left. \frac{\partial T}{\partial z} \right\vert_{z=0} =q(t), $

$\left. \frac{\partial T}{\partial z} \right\vert_{z=L} = 0,$

is a solution possible? I have a solution for the associated linear problem, which relied on the use of Duhamel's theorem but I am struggling to find mention of a non-linear solution.  I am currently using a finite difference scheme to model this problem  but was interested in the existence/viability of an exact answer.